# Merge two ordered linked lists into one ordered linked list

Tags: c, merge, linked-list

I've been trying to work on a code that will merge two ordered lists of integers into a single ordered list of integers.

The function `ListNodePtr merge( ListNodePtr xPtr, ListNodePtr yPtr )` is supposed to receive pointers to the first node of each of the two lists.

Everything else seems to work except for the merge function.

The problem seems to be that it cuts of the last element of the shorter list.

```
//12.7 merge two ordered lists into one ordered list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode
{
    int data;
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

    typedef struct listNode ListNode;
    typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;

    void insert( ListNodePtr *sPtr, int value );
    ListNodePtr merge( ListNodePtr xPtr, ListNodePtr yPtr );
    int isEmpty( ListNodePtr currentPtr );
    void printList( ListNodePtr currentPtr );
    void instructions(void);

int main(void)
{
    ListNodePtr startPtr1 = NULL;
    ListNodePtr startPtr2 = NULL;

    unsigned int choice;
    int item;

    instructions();
    printf("\n?");
    scanf("%u",&choice);

    while (choice != 4)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a character into list 1:\n");
            scanf("\n%d",&item);
            insert( &startPtr1, item );
            printList( startPtr1 );
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a character into list 2:\n");
            scanf("\n%d",&item);
            insert( &startPtr2, item );
            printList( startPtr2 );
            break;
        case 3:
            if (isEmpty(startPtr1) && isEmpty(startPtr2))
            {
                puts("Both lists are empty.");
            }
            else if (isEmpty(startPtr1))
            {
                puts("List 1 is empty.");
            }
            else if (isEmpty(startPtr2))
            {
                puts("List 2 is empty.");
            }
            else
            {
            printList( startPtr1 );
            printList( startPtr2 );
            puts("Merged list:");
            printList( merge( startPtr1, startPtr2 ) );
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.\n");
            instructions();
            break;
        }
        printf("\n?");
        scanf("%u",&choice);
    }
        puts("End of run.");
}

void instructions(void)
{
    printf("Enter your choice:\n"
    "   1 to insert an number into list 1.\n"
    "   2 to insert an number into list 2.\n"
    "   3 to merge and order list 1 and list 2.\n"
    "   4 to end.");
}

void insert( ListNodePtr *sPtr, int value )
{
    ListNodePtr newPtr;
    ListNodePtr previousPtr;
    ListNodePtr currentPtr;

    newPtr = (ListNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    if (newPtr != NULL)
    {
        newPtr->data = value;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        previousPtr = NULL;
        currentPtr = *sPtr;

        while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data)
        {
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if (previousPtr == NULL)
        {
                newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
                *sPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
        }
    }
    else
    {
            printf( "%d not inserted. No memory available.", value );
    }
}

ListNodePtr merge( ListNodePtr xPtr, ListNodePtr yPtr )
{
    ListNode merge; 
    ListNodePtr mergePtr = &merge;

    //PROBLEM: merge.nextPtr will be missing second to last element 
    //in final merged list

    while ( xPtr->nextPtr != NULL && yPtr->nextPtr != NULL)
    {
        if ( xPtr->data < yPtr->data)
        {
            mergePtr->nextPtr = xPtr;
            xPtr = xPtr->nextPtr;
            mergePtr = mergePtr->nextPtr;

        }//end if
        if ( yPtr->data < xPtr->data)
        {
            mergePtr->nextPtr = yPtr;
            yPtr = yPtr->nextPtr;
            mergePtr = mergePtr->nextPtr;
        }//end if
    }//end of while
    if ( xPtr->nextPtr == NULL )
    {
        mergePtr->nextPtr = yPtr;
    }
    if ( yPtr->nextPtr == NULL )
    {
        mergePtr->nextPtr = xPtr;
    }   
    return merge.nextPtr;
}//end of function merge


int isEmpty( ListNodePtr sPtr )
{
    return sPtr == NULL;
}

void printList( ListNodePtr currentPtr )
{
    if ( isEmpty(currentPtr) )
    {
        puts("List is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        while ( currentPtr != NULL )
        {
            printf("%d --> ", currentPtr->data);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        puts("NULL");
    }
}
```

Can anyone fix this problem? I've been learning the C programming language for a month and a half.

Comment: this is a great chance for you to learn how to debug your own code. You can easily step through this code through gdb or printing out relevant steps in the function to find at what point it all goes wrong

Comment: Hi, you merge function didn't return the fist pointer of megerList.And you may lose data when List1->data == List2->data. I modified it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I modified you code a little, and it work perfect!

```
//12.7 merge two ordered lists into one ordered list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode
{
   ! int data;
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

    typedef struct listNode ListNode;
    typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;

    void insert( ListNodePtr *sPtr, int value );
    ListNodePtr merge( ListNodePtr xPtr, ListNodePtr yPtr );
    int isEmpty( ListNodePtr currentPtr );
    void printList( ListNodePtr currentPtr );
    void instructions(void);

int main(void)
{
    ListNodePtr startPtr1 = NULL;
    ListNodePtr startPtr2 = NULL;

    unsigned int choice;
    int item;

    instructions();
    printf("\n?");
    scanf("%u",&choice);

    while (choice != 4)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a character into list 1:\n");
            scanf("\n%d",&item);
            insert( &startPtr1, item );
            printList( startPtr1 );
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a character into list 2:\n");
            scanf("\n%d",&item);
            insert( &startPtr2, item );
            printList( startPtr2 );
            break;
        case 3:
            if (isEmpty(startPtr1) && isEmpty(startPtr2))
            {
                puts("Both lists are empty.");
            }
            else if (isEmpty(startPtr1))
            {
                puts("List 1 is empty.");
            }
            else if (isEmpty(startPtr2))
            {
                puts("List 2 is empty.");
            }
            else
            {
            printList( startPtr1 );
            printList( startPtr2 );
            puts("Merged list:");
            printList( merge( startPtr1, startPtr2 ) );
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.\n");
            instructions();
            break;
        }
        printf("\n?");
        scanf("%u",&choice);
    }
        puts("End of run.");
}

void instructions(void)
{
    printf("Enter your choice:\n"
    "   1 to insert an number into list 1.\n"
    "   2 to insert an number into list 2.\n"
    "   3 to merge and order list 1 and list 2.\n"
    "   4 to end.");
}

void insert( ListNodePtr *sPtr, int value )
{
    ListNodePtr newPtr;
    ListNodePtr previousPtr;
    ListNodePtr currentPtr;

    newPtr = (ListNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

    if (newPtr != NULL)
    {
        newPtr->data = value;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        previousPtr = NULL;
        currentPtr = *sPtr;

        while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data)
        {
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if (previousPtr == NULL)
        {
                newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
                *sPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
        }
    }
    else
    {
            printf( "%d not inserted. No memory available.", value );
    }
}

ListNodePtr merge( ListNodePtr xPtr, ListNodePtr yPtr )
{
    ListNode merge; 
    ListNodePtr begin, mergePtr = &merge;          //here
    begin = mergePtr;                              //here
    //PROBLEM: merge.nextPtr will be missing second to last element 
    //in final merged list

    while ( xPtr != NULL && yPtr != NULL)      //here 2   now I deal with the last of short link!
    {
        if ( xPtr->data < yPtr->data)
        {
            mergePtr->nextPtr = xPtr;
            xPtr = xPtr->nextPtr;
            mergePtr = mergePtr->nextPtr;

        }//end if
        else// ( yPtr->data < xPtr->data)      //here for yPtr->data == xPtr->data
        {
            mergePtr->nextPtr = yPtr;
            yPtr = yPtr->nextPtr;
            mergePtr = mergePtr->nextPtr;
        }//end if
    }//end of while
    if ( xPtr != NULL )                          //here 2
    {
        mergePtr->nextPtr = xPtr;
    }
    if ( yPtr != NULL )                           //here 2
    {
        mergePtr->nextPtr = yPtr;
    }   
    return begin->nextPtr;                         //here
}//end of function merge


int isEmpty( ListNodePtr sPtr )
{
    return sPtr == NULL;
}

void printList( ListNodePtr currentPtr )
{
    if ( isEmpty(currentPtr) )
    {
        puts("List is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        while ( currentPtr != NULL )
        {
            printf("%d --> ", currentPtr->data);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        puts("NULL");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2616151 Yeah, but I fixed it now ,see //here 2 lines,and now it really work perfect

Answer (score 0):

Since you're checking if the NEXT value is null, when you hit your last value, you'll break out of your merge while loop.  Outside of this while loop, you should just append the other list onto the other one.  So if List1 runs out of elements and List2 has 3 more, instead of walking through List2, just make (end of List1)->next = (Where you left off in List2).

Also, don't return in the merge function.  You don't need to.  since yoru lists already occupy space, you're just switching around where their pointers are pointing.  Once all the pointers are done, just return from the function an access List1/List2 like you normally would (except you need to figure out which List contains the first pointer, so just return 1 or 2)

also, you don't ever set merge to a value I don't think

Answer (score 0):

```
ListNodePtr merge( ListNodePtr xPtr, ListNodePtr yPtr )
{
    ListNode merge; 
    ListNodePtr mergePtr = &merge;

    while ( xPtr != NULL && yPtr != NULL)
    {
        if ( xPtr->data < yPtr->data)
        {
            mergePtr->nextPtr = xPtr;
            xPtr = xPtr->nextPtr;
            mergePtr = mergePtr->nextPtr;

        } else if ( yPtr->data < xPtr->data)//need else because 1 loop 2 ecxecute merge
        {
            mergePtr->nextPtr = yPtr;
            yPtr = yPtr->nextPtr;
            mergePtr = mergePtr->nextPtr;
        }//end if
        //nothing case of (yPtr->data == xPtr->data)
    }//end of while
    if ( xPtr == NULL )
    {
        mergePtr->nextPtr = yPtr;
    }
    if ( yPtr == NULL )
    {
        mergePtr->nextPtr = xPtr;
    }   
    return merge.nextPtr;
}//end of function merge
```

Comment: @user2616151 Please show an example of cause problems specifically.